# How does this look like a tree?

Tags: set-theory, intuition, descriptive-set-theory

In a book there is a definition like that:

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the family of subsets $T$ of $S=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\mathbb{N}^n$ such that $\sigma  \mathord{\upharpoonright} k\in T$ whenever $\sigma\in T$ and $1\leq k\leq \#(\sigma)$. Menbers of $\mathcal{T}$ are often called **trees**.

An example I made: $\{(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3), (1, 3, 5), (5), (5, 4), (5, 4, 3)\}$.

How does this look like a tree? Is that a tree in the graph-theoretic sense of being connected and having no closed path?

Comment: What book?  What does $\sigma\upharpoonright k$ mean?

Comment: @kimchilover: A tuple is a function with a finite domain, so it is just the restriction of the tuple to a smaller domain. In other words, it is the "initial $k$-tuple of an $n$-tuple". That is a very standard notion in set theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it look like a tree?

[image: tree?]

Maybe.